# how can I change the tooltip color in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, colors, tooltip

There are ways to change the fontsize of, some, but not all, tooltips in Win10.

But I wanna change the tooltip **COLOR**, like it was possible in WinXP until Win7. Specifically, I want the tooltip background to be ***BLACK*** and the tooltip font to be ***GREEN***.

Please help.

I've looked at all the other answers Superuser says that are related, but none of them applied. Unless someone can show me how the likes of:

- How can I change the color of a BSOD?
- How can I change the color of the text that I have already written in OneNote?
- How can I change tab bar color in ConEmu

apply to my question, **of course** I'd be interested!

Comment: What tooltips? There are many different tooltips in Windows.

Comment: Please post links to what you have tried.

Comment: While I appreciate your time, gentlemen, I'm afraid that your follow ups don't give a lot of confidence in your ability to answer my question.
But let's do this dance:

1. WHAT tooltips? How about all of them?`

2. Superuser suggested the list below, none of which applied. But I am happy to learn how they DO apply to my question.`


`
    - `How do I change the dialog box title color in Windows 8? `

    - `How can I change the default Shape Fill color in Word 2007? `

    - `How can I update window/title color in Windows 10? `

    - `How can I change the color of a BSOD? `

Answer (score 2):

After experimenting long and hard I feel I'm entitled to my own answer here:

The key which works for me is:
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors**
with the StringValues of *InfoWindow* at 0 0 0 (for black background) and *InfoText* at 0 255 0 (for green text).
works on some tooltips, but not on taskbartooltips.

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors** doesn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change some colors in regedit. Press Windows Key And R: Type regedit and press Enter. Then find this folder:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors

Comment: [1] Yes. Thanks. Sadly there's not a key for tooltip colors there. Nor is there one in **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors**










     [2] And also, any change THERE reverts back to default values at reboot.